# Element width: 100% out of screen

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem. I set my top menu to `width: 100%`, but while loading, it goes out of screen (to always 522px).

**Debug**

I stopped page load with `debugger;` in console. Element's computed width is 522px. Clicking on that brings me to css `width: 100%`. Everything in the page stays within page width except the menu.

**CSS**

```
#mobile_header {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #5d3026;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 99998;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

**Weird part** 
It goes out of bounds only while loading. Whenever page finishes loading, it goes to normal 100% of full screen size. No additional JS affect this. No CSS is loaded (after the page load pause). I've also deleted all the contents from within, changed ID in html and css (so really no scripts would affect it), cleared cache. Still goes to weird 522px (that is translated from 100%). 
I know it's a wild shot, but does anyone has any guess of what could cause such a situation (on all browsers)?

[image]

Comment: have you tried on a real device with that ( or similar ) resolution??

Comment: @Vanojx1 yup - same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it turned out that my header (separate file from content) had another item with static length (50em) and `visibility:hidden` so as I looked in the page, i couldn't find anything. 
Noticed the cause only after taking apart all the header file. 
Long story short - if `width: 100%` is going out of screen and parents are normal size, there MUST be something static size in the content stretching it out. Thorough search will help.

Answer (score 3):

For `fixed` elements you can use `left: 0` and `right: 0` for 100% width

```
#mobile_header {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #5d3026;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; /* <= */
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 99998;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: so that's bug in this block' parents

Comment: Two direct parents are with no styling. Then body and html, that are both correctly with100% width.

Comment: ok. look for floating children and / or negative margins etc. i had such a problem twice before. maybe one of children fatter, then your block. paddings + 100% width or something...

Comment: Deleted all the page contents - left just that top menu. Still goes over. Sorcery!

Comment: that was cool to know! left & right will stretch it like 100%

Comment: and you can use `top` and `bottom` == `0` to stretch fixed or absolute etc block vertically :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `meta viewport` in your HTML for adjust the scale in mobile browsers?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: yes. it all has been done. everything worked well. and notice that overlow is happening only while loading..